# Centos7 Crontab jobs is not executing periodically

Tags: linux, cron, centos7, vps, cron-task

Am using a centos7 VPS server, recently I noticed that my website `Crontab` is not executing periodically on it own as scheduled. I have list of cron jobs but not of it will execute when the time come, but if I login to my `CWP web panel` and manually click run it will execute my command successfully.

Please how do I fix my Crontab issue?

[image]

```
0 0,12 * * * rm -rf /home/www/temp/*

* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/www/public_html/debug/cron.php >> /home/www/public_html/debug/_exec.log 2
```

In php cron.php

```
<?php 
 echo "Received Debugging Request";
?>
```

Comment: Could you please share the lines you are executing?

Comment: @aldegalan updated my question with the command

Comment: Try this `0 0,12 * * * rm -rf /home/www/temp/* > /tmp/crontab.log 2>&1` and inspect log.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I think, the crontab that is already configured should be changed to something like this:

```
1 0,12 * * * rm -rf /home/www/temp/*
```

Why is that?

Because the current configuration `0 0,12 * * * rm -rf /home/www/temp/*` means:

```
At minute 0 past hour 0 and 12.
```

is probably avoiding 00:00 and 12:00 because the condition says that it must execute after 00 and 12, it should be executed at 00:01 and 12:01.

Comment: I tried this also but not executing, I am thinking that the issue might not be from the configured jobs

Comment: @Peter Can you check logs? At the time it should be executing, maybe we can see something there

Comment: Please which log should I check?